# Django Python If statement not producing the expected result

Tags: django, if-statement

The following code if run in python console it worked fine and was able to get the expected result:

```
c2 = 1
stepCount = 4
workStepNo = 4
exeQueNum = 5

if c2 == 1:
    if stepCount == workStepNo:
            if exeQueNum == 5:
                actionChoice1 =3
            else:
                actionChoice1 = 2
    else:
            stepCount= int(stepCount)+1
            actionChoice1 = 1
else:
    actionChoice1 = 0

print "actionChoice1", actionChoice1
```

Was able to get print out on Python console on actionChoice1 correctly which is 3.

However, when the same code is used in Django it produced actionChoice as 2 and not 3 as expected.

```
if c2 == 1:
    if stepCount == workStepNo:
        if exeQueNum == 5:
            actionChoice =3
        else:
            actionChoice = 2
    else:
        stepCount= int(stepCount)+1
        actionChoice = 1
else:
    actionChoice = 0
```

Please help to pinpoint the errors that might have caused this.
What other alternative can be used to get the expected result in Django Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if exeQueNum == 5:
            actionChoice =3
        else:
            actionChoice = 2
```

`actionChoice` is 2 when `exeQueNum` is not 5. Please check how you're retrieving/producing the value of `exeQueNum` on Django. It does not equal to 5.

**Update:**

As the OP mentions, the value is `unicode` that is string. But it needs to be integer to be compared with another integer (5 in this case).

So do this:

```
    exeQueNum = int(exeQueNum)
    if exeQueNum == 5:
        actionChoice =3
    else:
        actionChoice = 2
```

Or you can also do `if int(exeQueNum) == 5` if you don't want to change the type of the variable.

Comment: Unicode is string. You are comparing to an integer. So you have to convert it to be an integer. Let me update my answer.